# Show that problem of Shortest-Path in digraph is in NL

Tags: complexity-theory

Look at solution to exercise 2, please.
Exercise and solution is derieved from:
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172-07/solutions/sol8.pdf

> $$ShortestPath = \{(G, k, s, t)| \text{the shortest path from $s$ to
> > $t$ in $G$ has length $k$}\}$$ (a) Prove that $ShortestPath$ is in
>   $NL$.
>
> (a) Solution:   We construct a $NL$-machine for ShortestPath as
>   follows: on input $\langle G, k, s, t\rangle$, first compute $r_{k−1}$
>   (the number of vertices reachable from $s$ in at most $k − 1$ steps).
>   Then, on input $\langle G = (V, E), k, s, t\rangle$ and $r_{k−1}$ on
>   the work tape,
>
> ```
> d ← 0
> flag ← FALSE
> for all w ∈ V do
> p ← s
> for i ← 1 to k − 1 do
> non-deterministically pick a neighbor q of p
> if p = w then
> d ← d + 1
> if w = t reject
> if w is a neighbor of t then
> flag ← TRUE
> if d < r_{k−1} reject
> if flag then accept else reject
> ```

I don't know why it is so complex.
Tell me please, why direct and simple algorithm is not ok:
Check if there exists path from $s$ to $t$ of length $1$
Check if there exists path from $s$ to $t$ of length $2$
...
Check if there exists path from $s$ to $t$ of length $k-1$
If there exists path of length $\le k -1 $ then reject. Else check if exists length of $k$ and accept if exists.

In other words we check one be one each length. We can check existence of path thanks to non-determinism. We launch number of visited nodes and check if we end up in $t$

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is how to check using non-deterministic logarithmic space that there is no path from $s$ to $t$ of some length $\ell$. We cannot just go over all possible paths of length $\ell$ since in order to do this we will need to "remember" $\ell$ vertices, whereas we are only allowed to remember $O(1)$ vertices (since each vertex takes up $\Theta(\log n)$ space).

If we want to check that there *exists* a path of length $\ell$, we can simply guess the path vertex-by-vertex and check that it leads from $s$ to $t$; this only requires counting up to $\ell$, which takes logarithmic space (since we're only interested in $\ell < n$). But it's not so clear how to check that there *doesn't* exist a path of length $\ell$ – what would be a witness for that?

The solution is to use the technique of *inductive counting*, invented for the proof of the [Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem), which states that NL=coNL. This is what the solution uses.

Comment: When it comes to my solution. I must remember nodes on path to avoid cycles ? I thought that I give algorithm in $P^{NL}$, not $NL$ because I use some sub-algorithm in $NL$ as oracle. Hmm ?

Comment: I don't know about your algorithm, but the question asks for an algorithm which can be implemented by an NL machine. Indeed, $P^{NL} = P$, which is conjectured to be larger than $NL$.

Comment: @MathMaster this technique is described in Sipser's book, when NL=coNL is proved (pg. 327)

Comment: @Yuval could you look at me approach in question ? Is it $P^{NL}$ or $NL$?

Comment: You don't really explain your approach, but it seems that what you intended is a $P^{NL}$ machine.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, however I am using $NL$ space, so it is $NL$ or $P^{NL}$

Comment: I think that the heart of your confusion is that you don't quite understand the complexity class NL. It consists of all languages accepted by nondeterministic Turing machines using logarithmic work space. Unfortunately nondeterminism is counterintuitive. In particular, people find it hard to understand why NP is (potentially) different from coNP. Try to rewrite your algorithm using the "witness" interpretation of nondeterminism and see what goes wrong.

Comment: *We cannot just go over all possible paths of length ℓ since in order to do this we will need to "remember" ℓ vertices* Why ??? After all we only must remember how many verticles we used. So counter for $l$.

Comment: No need for all the question marks. I suggest that you try to write an algorithm $A(G,s,t,\ell,w)$, where $w$ is a witness, using logarithmic space, with the following two properties: (1) if there is no path of length $\ell$ from $s$ to $t$ in $G$ then there exists a witness $w$ such that the algorithm accepts, (2) if there is a path of length $\ell$ from $s$ to $t$ in $G$ then the algorithm rejects for all witnesses $w$.